# Does numba jitclass support generics?

Tags: python, generics, numba

Looking at the Stack code in the numba examples: https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/examples/stack.py
the Stack class looks like its written independently of the stack's element type, yet the final stack is instantiated as a Stack of int, and looks like can't be reused for other types.

Is this the cases, or can Stack be reused to contain other types?

Comment: Add a language tag please

Answer (score 1):

The best I've found is to wrap it in a function. I  don't particularly like this:

```
@numba.jit
def make_stack_class(typ):
    linkednode_spec = OrderedDict()
    linkednode_type = deferred_type()
    linkednode_spec['data'] = data_type = deferred_type()
    linkednode_spec['next'] = optional(linkednode_type)

    @jitclass(linkednode_spec)
    class LinkedNode(object):
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data
            self.next = None


    linkednode_type.define(LinkedNode.class_type.instance_type)

    stack_spec = OrderedDict()
    stack_spec['head'] = optional(linkednode_type)
    stack_spec['size'] = intp


    @jitclass(stack_spec)
    class Stack(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.head = None
            self.size = 0

        def push(self, data):
            new = LinkedNode(data)
            new.next = self.head
            self.head = new
            self.size += 1

        def pop(self):
            old = self.head
            if old is None:
                raise ValueError("empty")
            else:
                self.head = old.next
                self.size -= 1
                return old.data



    data_type.define(typ)
    return Stack
```